# Flagging a question as spam votes "no" and gives the owner more rep

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, flags, area-51

I just flagged [this question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications/1583#1583) as spam while it was at 1 Yes / 1 No, refreshed, and the question then had 1 Yes / 2 No. I also noticed the owner got +5 rep for that No vote (and no -2 which I would have expected).

It's possible someone actually voted on it, but I think this needs to be looked at.

Comment: If this turns out to be true, it would be a funny bug (here flagging downvotes, which gives -2, I guess the same code runs there except the "no" vote gives you +5 (as you say))

Comment: Let's all test by spam-flagging everything @Jon has ever posted

Comment: Oh dear god. I finally actually clicked the link to see the question -- is there any aspect of SO he hasn't infected?

Comment: @Juan: That explanation makes a lot of sense. Could you try flagging that question and seeing what happens? (The rep will get sorted out by itself with a recalc once this bug -- assuming it is a bug -- gets fixed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops!  This should be fixed now...

Answer (score 2):

I got the same behavior; flagging as spam pushed it to 1 yes/3 no and he went from 180 to 185 reputation. I'm off to prepare my army of spam-bots that will shortly be Area 51 pseudo-mods